# Compressing bitmap image in corona

Tags: bitmap, lua, compression, coronasdk

Specifically in Lua, is there a way to compress the file size of an image?

In my app the user can take or choose an image which is then saved to the temp directory of the app.

Later, it is uploaded to the server but when the connection is slow, it times out. Even when the connection is good it takes long and uses a lot of data when connected to cellular connection.

Compressing the bitmap file should be simple and the easiest solution.

I have spent days stuck on this, searching for solutions, but found no documentation for this anywhere for how to do it in Lua - there are many solutions in other languages. I

If anyone has done this I really need help :/

Another way to go about it I though of is writing the code in a different language, and then interpreting it in Lua - anyone know how to approach that?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of images user uploads?

Comment: They upload jpg files

Answer (score 0):

The display.save() functions can generate either .PNG or .JPEG files.  JPEG files are compressed more than .PNG files.  There are no controls that allow you to control the amount of compression that's being used by the JPEGs.  They are as small as Corona SDK can get them.

Rob